# rsync script work on CentOS 7, same script doesn't work on RHEL 7

Tags: linux, centos, rsync, flock

I have a VM cluster with 3 nodes on CentOS7 and one node on RHEL7. There is a directory where rsync is enabled `/mnt/<server_IP>/portal/wso2telcohub-3.0.2/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/`
incrontab is set as below.

```
$ incrontab -l
/mnt/<server_IP>/portal/wso2telcohub-3.0.2/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/ IN_MODIFY,IN_ATTRIB,IN_CREATE,IN_DELETE /mnt/rsync/rsync-for-carbon-depsync.sh
```

rsync script with debug enabled

```
#!/bin/sh -ex
#source folder
portal=/mnt/<server_IP>/portal/wso2telcohub-3.0.2/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/
#Destination folder
gateway=/mnt/<server_IP>/gateway/wso2telcohub-3.0.2/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
LOG=/log/rsync/carbon-rsync-logs/"log-local-$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).log"

echo "entered the script" >> $LOG

#keep a lock to stop parallel runs
(
echo "entered the flock" >> $LOG
flock -e 10
echo "Obtained the lock" >> $LOG
echo " ========== $(date -Iseconds) Lock acquired by local thread <server_IP>< =========== " >> $LOG
rsync --delete -arv $portal   $gateway  >>  $LOG
) 10> /var/rsync/.rsync.lock
echo " ========== $(date -Iseconds) Release Lock acquired by local thread <server_IP> =========== " >> $LOG
```

Below is the log file

```
entered the script
entered the script
```

Basically, whatever the change done on `portal` should reflect on `gateway`.
I created a temp file in `portal` directory. But it doesn't reflect in `gateway` directory.
This is only for the new RHEL 7 VM. Old CentOS 7 VM works fine with same script.

Comment: What debugging have you attempted? Can you confirm that your script is triggered by `incrond` when a file is created? (I see your "entered the script" but is that on the working system or the non-working system? Do the lines correspond with your tests or are they picking up something else?)

Comment: Debugging: just the echos. Yes, scrip is triggered by incrond. "entered the script" is from the non working system. Lines corresponding to my test

Comment: You need to identify why your script can't write `entered the flock` to the logfile. Permissions on `/var/rsync/.rsync.lock` maybe? What I'd do is put `exec 2>/tmp/errors` as the second line of the script, and investigate that for error messages.

Comment: @roaima: Thanks a lot for the tip. I checked ```/var/rsync/.rsync.lock```. But there is no ```rsync``` directory inside ```/var``` for RHEL 7, for CenOS 7, I have the specified file above. How can we proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advised you to enable error reporting to a log file `/tmp/errors` by adding a new command at line two. Extending this a little, we get this modification that captures expected output and unexpected errors to a single file, `/tmp/output`:

```
#!/bin/sh -ex
exec >/tmp/output 2>&1

#source folder
portal=/mnt/<server_IP>/portal/wso2telcohub-3.0.2/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/
...
```

In a production environment one would write to a better defined log file, or even use the system logger (`man logger` for details).

The shell `-e` flag causes it to exit as soon as it executes a command that returns a non-success status (non-zero exit code). The error log will capture the output generated as a consequence of any error just as the shell exits. The `-x` flag enables tracing - also to the log file.

In a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584890/rsync-script-work-on-centos-7-same-script-doesnt-work-on-rhel-7?noredirect=1#comment1089263_584890) you determined that, "*there is no rsync directory inside `/var` for RHEL 7*".

So, the reason your script is not working on RHEL 7 is because you have not created this  directory that the script requires. The script tries to write to `/var/rsync/.rsync.lock` but it cannot do so because the parent directory does not exist.

The solution is to create the directory and ensure that the UID that executes your script can write to it. Better still, modify the script to create the directory if it doesn't already exist, or to report this error in some manner that can be captured and made available to a real person.

Comment: Thanks friend. It worked.